# opencv: undefined reference to `cv::cuda::DescriptorMatcher::createBFMatcher(int)'

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to complie `opencv-3.1.0/samples/gpu/surf_keypoint_matcher.cpp` through:

`g++ -I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include/opencv2 -L/usr/local/lib/ -g -o binary  surf_keypoint_matcher.cpp -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_ml -lopencv_video -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_xfeatures2d`

But I'm getting this error:

```
/tmp/ccQW7t3Z.o: In function `main':
/home/luca/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/samples/gpu/surf_keypoint_matcher.cpp:65: undefined reference to `cv::cuda::DescriptorMatcher::createBFMatcher(int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Why?

Comment: The cuda versions are in cudafeatures2d you need to include and link to this

Comment: You mean opencv_cudafeatures2d? ;) That's right answer sir, If you'll post it I'll chose it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error message:

```
/home/luca/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/samples/gpu/surf_keypoint_matcher.cpp:65: undefined reference to `cv::cuda::DescriptorMatcher::createBFMatcher(int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

shows that you have an undefined reference to `cv::cuda::DescriptorMatcher::createBFMatcher`

this resides in the cuda libs so you need to include the appropriate headers and link into the following libs as `opencv_cudafeatures2d` depends on them:

- opencv_cudafilters
- opencv_cudawarping
- opencv_features2d
- opencv_cudaarithmn
- opencv_flann
- opencv_core

certainly this is true for opencv version 3.1.0 which is what I'm using

Answer (score 0):

[DescriptorMatcher is in `cudafeatures2d.hpp`](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/dd/dc5/classcv_1_1cuda_1_1DescriptorMatcher.html). So, you have to include the header `cudafeatures2d.hpp` in the .cpp program and [link the library in the compile process](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Linking-programs-with-the-library.html#Linking-programs-with-the-library).

The program runs if you use this `-lopencv_cudafeatures2d`:

`g++ -I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include/opencv2 -L/usr/local/lib/ -g -o binary  surf_gpu_probe1.cpp -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_ml -lopencv_video -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_xfeatures2d -lopencv_cudafeatures2d`